# How do I override menu items with my own implementation?

Tags: 7, routes, users

My specific use case is this: I don't want users accessing the user/%user/edit menu. This is awkward because it's quite embedded in Drupal, e.g. forgotten password system. I want the drupal form for admins, but I want a different form for end-users because I do not want to expose certain user fields to them, and because some updates they may need to do need to be handled by an external database, so changing them in Drupal is unhelpful.

Using `hook_form_alter()` is not really going to cut it; it really does need to be quite a different form.

I had planned to override the user/%user/edit path by using my own module. This would then check if the accessing user was an admin, and if so, present the stock form, but if not it would `drupal_goto('client/updates');` but this doesn't work; my module's page callback never gets called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`hook_menu_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to reroute the request for that page to your own module's functions:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/%user/edit']['access callback'] = 'MYMODULE_access_callback';
  $items['user/%user/edit']['page callback'] = 'MYMODULE_user_edit_page_callback';
}

function MYMODULE_access_callback($account) {
  if ($something) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  return TRUE;
}

function MYMODULE_user_edit_page_callback($account) {
  if ($something) {
    return drupal_get_form('some_form');
  }
  else {
    return drupal_get_form('some_other_form');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. I had also got it working by putting my code in `hook_form_alter()` but I wasn't happy with this as it's not really the place for a drupal_goto.